# Python Pandas Convert columns to list from dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I've been getting lists in emails with line breaks for each item what I want to do is just copy and paste then save as csv and have a script create a python list out of the data. Since it's columns from the paste to the file I'm getting improper formatting, if I change I do a replace on the line breaks for commas it look a bit better but still since it's converted from a column it's not correct and with mylist.values.tolist() it still doesn't work. Here's what I have and what's happening. I can do this with the builtin csv library but was wondering how to do it in p

Email format that I'm pasting:

Fox
Chicken
Cat
Dog

When I put into csv and put the commas:

Fox,
Chicken,
Cat,
Dog

What I get back for output:

> > > mylist.values.tolist()

```
[['Fox, nan'], ['Chicken, nan'], ['Cat, nan'], ['Dog, nan']]
```

I just want:

```
['Fox','Chicken', 'Cat', 'Dog']
```

Further, if I try to assign my_list = mylist.values.tolist() I get an exception the unsupported operands 'str' and 'type'.

Any help would be appreciated since I like pandas more than builtin, if it's not possible elegantly I'll have to go back.

Comment: Are you sure your output is exactly as you typed it? Is it not `[['Fox', nan], ['Chicken', nan], ['Cat', nan], ['Dog', nan]]`?

Comment: what type is `mylist`? the exception in the assignment is strange, how could I duplicate it? please, put a small minimal but complete example of the exception.

Comment: You are correct, it's a couple hundred mac addresses so I didn't copy and paste, sorry.

Comment: @eguaio 
>>> type(mylist)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
I can add code but it's really just a list copied into excel columns and read with pandas.

Comment: @Fallacy11 what columns the dataframe has? are they named?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
slist = mylist.values.tolist()
ilist = [l[0].split(',')[0].strip() for l in slist]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your output is `[['Fox', nan], ['Chicken', nan], ['Cat', nan], ['Dog', nan]]` (which I believe it is), then you can unzip the list into two parts:

```
names,nans=zip(*mylist.values.tolist()) 
# both names and nuns are tuples
names = list(names)
```

Comment: I would agree it is a little strange, but the `tolist()` method really returns a list of strings encoding all the values separated by comma, as stated in the question. This will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The formatting from the copy-pasting is somehow causing pandas to think you've given it a (4 x 2) table. So in this particular case, if your dataframe is `mylist`, you'll want `mylist.iloc[:,0].values.tolist()`.

But really, just reading the file into a string and calling `.split()` is much simpler, faster and more robust.